# What properties does $\mathcal{L}$ guarantee in Euler-Lagrange Differential Equation?

Tags: calculus, mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations

Let's say that $y = f(x)$ is not a function of position - but rather some function of an arbitrary data feature $x$.

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} \mathcal{L}}{\mathrm{d} y} -\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x} \left(\frac{\mathrm{d} \mathcal{L}}{\mathrm{d} y'}\right) = 0
$$

If we solve for $\mathcal{L}$ what properties does the functional guarantee, and how to interpret it in plain english (not in terms of the action integral)?

Comment: I'd say that it'd still describe some sort of geometry, in the sense that it generates the geometry of f(x) in some abstract (y,x) space. The Lagrangean would also still be tied with some kind of "total value" (because the Euler-Lagrange equations come from extremizing the integral of it, which **kind of** is its "total value"). So solving the EL equations for $\mathcal{L}$, given some "curve" f, would give you the function for which the "curve" extremizes its "total value" . This is my best attempt at interpreting it in plain english; it's still very abstract without a concrete example tho.

Comment: @LourencoEntrudo Thank you - its very useful. I was hoping to hear that it would still minimize something...

Comment: well, it still has a relationship with something that is being extremized

Comment: Hi Edv Beq: 1. What does your first sentence (after the title) mean? 2. Also what do you call position: $x$ or $y$?

Comment: @Qmechanic When I read about EL - the typical examples are always related to position and velocity. All I am saying is that what if we have something arbitrary (i.e.: a regression problem) - does the EL diff eq guarantee anything? For example, if it minimizes "something" - can we use it as a cost function in a machine learning algorithm. Just a thought

Comment: @EdvBeq EL will minimize/maximize the integral of the Lagrangean. I don't know anything about cost functions, but if you have some f(x) you can find an L such that the integral of L is extremized, and likewise if you got something of which integral you want to have minimized/maximized, then there is a corresponding f(x) that you can find through EL